# Is there an API for USAID's Aidtracker-Plus?

Tags: data-request, iati, usaidopen

We've seen Aidtracker+ implementations at some country Missions. Is there an API available to access the underlying data?

Alternatively is there a way to pull the data out of the SalesForce backend similar to what the American Red Cross is doing? (https://github.com/AmericanRedCross/GeoForce)

Answer (score 3):

USAID does not currently have a publicly available API for AIDtracker Plus. However, we are looking into specifications and requirements for a comprehensive data collection and reporting system that would have similar capabilities to AIDtracker Plus.  Please see references in the second Quadrennial Diplomacy and Development Review ([QDDR](http://www.state.gov/documents/organization/241429.pdf)) (pages 12 and 54) for "Development Information Solution" or DIS.  Once we have finalized the target architecture for DIS, we do plan to develop an API.